# Build with Maven in Eclipse Photon - How to get console colours?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I read that the console output of Maven 3.5.x has colours, but in my Eclipse Photon (with integrated Maven 3.5.3), there are no colours. Did I misunderstand the announcement or do I need to activate the colourful output somehow?

Comment: There might be a few hiccups there: 1) I suspect the enhancement is designed for native consoles and 2) it might not work with CMD.exe if you're on Windows - see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3507) mostly. Maybe combining it with an ANSI coloring [plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console) will do the trick?

Comment: @Mena The color will work on linux, Windows (the linked issue was related to Maven 3.5.0 but not on Maven 3.5.3+ apart from details it works on cmd as well) and MacOS console fine. The issue is in Eclipse (not really an ansi compatible console) so you should check the Eclipse Plugin. To be honest I never run Maven within the Eclipse console...

Comment: @khmarbaise ah yes I didn't check the 3.5.3+ specifically. Maven is pretty well integrated with Eclipse in my (limited) experience nowadays, but the Eclipse console is definitely not the same as a native console, regardless of the OS. Hopefully that plugin might work for the OP.

Answer (score 5):

You can install [m2e-chromatic](https://github.com/sidespin/m2e-chromatic) from the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-chromatic). It automatically adds the proper jansi flags to Maven's launch configurations. It depends on the *[ANSI Escape in Console plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console)* being installed (this is done automatically when installing m2e-chromatic).

[image: m2e-chromatic]